# git diff directories commit with inplace working tree files

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

My question is related to a question I asked some time ago: [Git diff directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841994/git-diff-of-branches-or-commits-showing-file-list-overview-in-visual-difftool-an).

This works but it copies the current working tree files to a temporary folder. So actually I am only comparing copies.

What I would like to do is compare a commit to the real working tree and not a copy of the working tree. In this case I could work on the real files taking single lines to my current source inside my diff tool (Beyondcompare - Windows platform).

I tried several commands:

```
git difftool -d commit1
git difftool -d commit1 HEAD
git difftool -d commit1 [WorkingFolder]
```

Nothing worked. Beyondcompare opens: `/tempfolder_left/` compared to `/tempfolder_right/`.

Changes in the difftool are, of course, not copied to the working folder then.

Is this possible at all?